# Qt - difference between drawPolyline and drawLine

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, coordinate-transformation

In my example I transformed the coordinate system of the qt painter in the following way:

```
 QTransform xform;
 xform.rotate(90);
 xform.scale(1, 1000000000000000);
 xform.translate(0, -std::abs(max));
 if (limit != 0)
     xform.scale(1, std::abs(max)/std::abs(limit));
 painter->setTransform(xform)
```

There is such a big scale because I have very small data in my example. Then I draw the plot for my data - it's values are about 1e-14 and everything is drawn correctly. Then I want to draw couple of lines in addition to my plot specified by two points.

I apply drawPolyLine function:

```
QPointF* line = new QPointF[2];
line[0].setX(0);
line[0].setY(0);
line[1].setX(0);
line[1].setY(std::abs(seismMax));
painter.drawPolyline(line, 2);
```

where seismMax is of the orders of 1e-14 ( as all my points in the plot). And the line is drawn.
Then I apply drawLine ( as I have only two points):

```
painter.drawLine(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(0, std::abs(seismMax)));
```

And in this case line is not drawn. I suspect that maybe these two functions process coordinates differently. As when I draw the line with drawLine in original scale (for example like this) :

```
 painter.drawLine(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(0, 1000));
```

the line is drawn correctly.

Comment: 1. I looked into Qt doc. and couldn't find any described difference. 2. I looked into [`QPainter` source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpainter.cpp.html) on woboq.org. There are many different options to draw a line where most of them end up in the same functions called from an engine. So, there shouldn't really be any difference. I may have overlooked something. However, I'm quite sure that this is a bug in one specific engine. So, you may look for an update of your Qt version or simply use `drawPolyline()` exclusively to work around the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to come in touch with the problem.

Thereby, I used much smaller scalings and was not able to reproduce the issue. Then, I used the scaling 1.0E14 as stated by OP. Suddenly, the line drawings disappeared. Lowering the scaling, I fiddled out that (in my case) upto `1E12` it worked quite good but with higher scalings lines begun to disappear. While toying with this, a colleague came away and provided the hint that this might been simply floating point issues. We shortly discussed this and came to the conclusion:

- multiplying very big numbers with very small is not a problem at all. It consists of (integer) multiplying the mantissas and adding the exponents.
- addition/subtraction of big numbers with very small *is* a problem as both numbers have to made with equal exponents (by bit-shifting mantissas) to add/subtract mantissas.

So, the latter might happen which erases the non-0 values to 0.

10<sup>14</sup> is in binary a number with 47 digits. This is close to the precision of `double` with 53 bits mantissa. **But**: the used rendering engine of `QPainter` may be based on OpenGL where `float` is the default for many things. `float` provides only 23 bits for mantissa!

So, after thinking a bit about this, I found good reasons not to paint with a scaling factor of 10<sup>14</sup>.

To demonstrate this, I made a small sample `testQPainterDrawLine.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget {
  public:
    const double scale; 
  public:
    Widget(double scale, QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent),
      scale(scale)
    { }
    virtual ~Widget() = default;
    Widget(const Widget&) = delete;
    Widget& operator=(const Widget&) = delete;
  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  const double value = height() / scale;
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  qPainter.fillRect(0, 0, width(), height(), QColor(Qt::white));
  qPainter.drawRect(0, 0, width() - 1, height() - 1);
  QTransform xform;
  xform.scale(1, scale);
  qPainter.setTransform(xform);
  qPainter.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::red), 3.0));
  const double xL = 0.333 * width();
  qPainter.drawLine(QPointF(xL, 0.0), QPointF(xL, value));
  qPainter.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::blue), 3.0));
  const double xPL = 0.667 * width();
  QPointF qPts[] = { QPointF(xPL, 0.0), QPointF(xPL, value) };
  const int nPts = sizeof qPts / sizeof *qPts; 
  qPainter.drawPolyline(qPts, nPts);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWin;
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  qGrid.setRowStretch(0, 0); qGrid.setRowStretch(1, 1);
  double scale = 1.0E11;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i, scale *= 10.0) {
    qGrid.addWidget(
      new QLabel(QString("Scale: %1").arg(scale)),
      0, i);
    qGrid.addWidget(new Widget(scale), 1, i);
  }
  qWin.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWin.resize(1024, 256);
  qWin.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQPainterDrawLine.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQPainterDrawLine.cc

QT = widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQPainterDrawLine.pro

$ make

$ ./testQPainterDrawLine
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: snapshot of testQPainterDrawLine]

So, finally, I believe, it hasn't anything to do with `QPainter::drawLine()` vs. `QPainter::drawPolyline()`. It's simply the scaling which is too high and causes floating point issues. That's why lines may accidentally (dis-)appear.

The solution is simple: The values have to be scaled before drawing them with `QPainter`, so that internal transformations in `QPainter` happen in magnitudes closer to 0 and 1.